# Официальный каталог стандартов ГОСТ и ISO

Tags: iso, гост

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где можно найти официальный и наиболее актуальный каталог ГОСТ'ов и стандартов ISO?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[каталог ГОСТов от Росреестра](http://old.gost.ru/wps/portal/pages/directions?WCM_GLOBAL_CONTEXT=/gost/GOSTRU/directions/Standardization/standards/catalog), официальнее некуда.

Answer (score 4):

ISO - на [официальном сайте](https://www.iso.org/standards-catalogue/browse-by-ics.html). Тексты ГОСТов в свободный доступ официально не выкладываются, ими в России торгуют.

Comment: ISO тоже не бесплатен.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.
"Тексты ГОСТов в свободный доступ официально не выкладываются ... " и "ISO тоже не бесплатен"  Мне кажется, что такое положение дел весьма печально.

Comment: Увы, это вопрос политики. Проявляйте гражданскую активность, заявляйте общественные инициативы, требуйте свободного доступа к данным, поддерживайте пиратскую партию. На РОИ происходит вялое шевеление на схожие темы, например - https://www.roi.ru/10119/

Comment: Безгрифные ГОСТы свободно гуляют по интернетам, и Росстандарт даже не пытается с этим бороться, потому что незачем - Вы можете спокойно ознакомиться со стандартом, но разговор об имплементации того или иного стандарта на предприятии начинается с предоставления официальной копии